# Shell script using FFMPEG convert to mp4 results in new video with .mp4 extension attached twice

Tags: linux, shell, ffmpeg

I am converting an entire folder of videos to MP4. The script works except that the new videos have ".mp4" attached twice to them. For example. 'video.mp3' would be 'video.mp3.mp4' after conversion. Below is the shell script. TIA

```
#!/bin/bash
#Shell Script which converts all videos in a folder to MP4


for file in *.*; 
    do 
        if[ ${file: -4} != ".mp4"]   #don't want to convert mp4 files           
            ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file}".mp4 
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will strip the last file extension: `${file%.*}`

So you'd want `${file%.*}.mp4`

Here is a good reference for string manipulation in bash: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: This solution works. The reference is helpful for anyone learning shell scripting.